# pecl uploadprogress installed, but I don't see it anywhere

Tags: 7, files

I've successfully installed the [PECL uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) extension and restarted my server. Here's an exerpt from phpinfo():

[image]

However, when I add a piece of content and I choose to upload a photo or a video or a generic file, all I see is the normal ajax spinner but I don't see any kind of upload progress UI that I see on the drupal site ([Install PECL uploadprogress](http://drupal.org/node/793264)), which looks like this:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, I stumbled upon it right after posting. It needs to be configured on each Field in particular. I edited my Content Type and changed this setting:

[image]