# PECL uploadprogress installed - but no progress bar, just spinning gif

Tags: files

Pretty much same question as [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34629/pecl-uploadprogress-installed-but-i-dont-see-it-anywhere).  I've set everything up - can confirm pecl uploadprogress is on, and activated from the status reports page.

But how do I see this for uploading files? I've recently enabled the handy drag and drop upload module from [here](https://drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload) - which supports the progress bar, but whenever I upload something it's just a spinning gif.  I can't find where to alter the progress indicator as mentioned in the answer in the first link above - can anyone point me in the direction?

cheers

Comment: having the same problem. We should probably post an issue on the module's issue page :)

Comment: Just spotted the issue you posted! Think I managed to fix it.. check out below>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this by changing the widget type of the field - back to normal 'File'. Then if you go to the manage field display for this, you should now have an option to set the progress indicator to either 'Throbber' or 'Progress Bar'. If you select progress bar, then flip the widget type back to drag n drop module - it seems to do the trick. Cheers